# Python Tkinter: pass a function with a variable into a button that calls the function and passing the var into a entry form

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

This is my first time asking a question on here so bear with me. I am attempting to make a GUI that will transfer any new/updated text files from one file to another. The GUI should also display the date of the last file transfer as a reference. My main issue is that my functions that grab my files run automatically instead of on the button press. What can I do to fix it to where they only run when the respective buttons are pressed.

```
import sqlite3
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter as tk
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import os
import shutil

databaseName = 'last_check.sqlite'
#make table
def datetime_tbl():
    conn = sqlite3.connect(databaseName)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS datetime_tbl(datestamp TEXT)');
    c.close()
    conn.close()
#grab entry from ui
def data_entry():
    conn = sqlite3.connect(databaseName)
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("INSERT INTO datetime_tbl (datestamp) VALUES (?)", 
(str(datetime.now()),))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

#this grabs file transfer from tbl for entry form              
def generatelasttransfer():
    conn = sqlite3.connect(databaseName)
    c = conn.cursor()
    global transfer
    transfer = c.execute("""SELECT MAX(datestamp) FROM datetime_tbl ORDER BY 
        datestamp DESC LIMIT 1""").fetchall() 
    #print(transfer)#testing
    return(transfer)
    c.close()
    #conn.close()    

def ui(root):
    transfer = StringVar()
    transfer.set(generatelasttransfer())
    src_filename = StringVar()
    src_filename.set(src_files())
    des_filename = StringVar()
    des_filename.set(des_files())

    #btn for main file transfer 
    btn_ck = tk.Button(text='File Transfer',command= f_transfer).grid(row = 
        7, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    #btns for src and des files
    btn_src = tk.Button(text='Choose file to send out',command= 
        src_files).grid(row = 2, column = 2, padx = 5, pady = 5)
    btn_des = tk.Button(text='Choose file to send to',command= 
        des_files).grid(row = 2, column = 4, padx = 5, pady = 5)

    tk.Entry(text= src_filename).grid(row = 3, column = 2, padx = 15, pady = 5)
    tk.Entry(text= des_filename).grid(row = 3, column = 4, padx = 15, pady = 5)
    tk.Entry(root, textvariable = transfer, width=28).grid(row = 7,column = 4,padx = 7,pady = 7)

def src_files():
    global src_filename
    src_filename =  filedialog.askdirectory()
    return src_filename
def des_files():
    global des_filename
    des_filename =  filedialog.askdirectory()
    return des_filename
#file transfer
def f_transfer():
    for root,dirs,files in os.walk(src_filename):
        for file_name in files:
            now = datetime.now()
            before = now - timedelta(hours=24)
            files = os.path.join(src_filename, file_name)
            mod_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(files))
            if mod_time > before:
                shutil.move(os.path.join(src_filename, file_name), 
                    des_filename)
                data_entry()  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    datetime_tbl()
    root = Tk()
    root.mainloop
    ui(root)
```

Answer (score 1):

Closures are very handy here since the data containers here (`src_filename`, `dest_filename`) are mutable `StringVar` objects.

First, `src_files()` and `des_files()` can be refactored to a single function. Let's lose the use of those globals.

```
def get_file(src_filename):
    def wrap():
        src_filename.set(filedialog.askdirectory())
    return wrap
```

This will be passed as button commands like so:

```
btn_src = tk.Button(
    text='Choose file to send out',
    command=get_file(src_filename)
).grid(
    row=2, column=2, padx=5, pady=5
)

btn_des = tk.Button(
    text='Choose file to send to',
    command=get_file(des_filename)
).grid(row=2, column=4, padx=5, pady=5)
```

`f_transfer` will also close over `src_filename`, and `des_filename` as it uses both names.

```
def f_transfer(src_filename, des_filename):
    def wrap():
        _src_filename, _des_filename = src_filename.get(), des_filename.get()

        for root,dirs,files in os.walk(_src_filename):
            for file_name in files:
                now = datetime.now()
                before = now - timedelta(hours=24)
                files = os.path.join(_src_filename, file_name)
                mod_time = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(files))
                if mod_time > before:
                    shutil.move(
                        os.path.join(_src_filename, file_name), 
                        _des_filename
                    )
                    data_entry()
    return wrap
```

We'll bind both names to `f_transfer` before passing it as command for `btn_ck`.

```
btn_ck = tk.Button(
    text='File Transfer',
    command=f_transfer(src_filename, des_filename)
).grid(
    row=7, column=2, padx=5, pady=5
)
```

**Bonus**: we need to run the mainloop after setting up GUI components et Voila!

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    datetime_tbl()
    root = Tk()
    ui(root)
    root.mainloop()
```